# RoR SendGrid error in configuration, will not allow deploy to Heroku; Ch 10 Hartl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org, sendgrid

I've done this bit of configuration for SendGrid exactly to the tutorial, searched a lot for answers, still getting this error when attempting to push to heroku:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `auto' for #<SampleApp::Application:0x007f5c8bdaef78>
```

The line throwing up the error:

```
:enable_starttls_auto => true
```

Full code from config/environments.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'gentle-sands-4285.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Really appreciate any help, and hopefully will be helpful to others learning through the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding this to your config/environment.rb file, try adding this the files within your config/environments/ folder. Here is what I did:

I added this to my config/environments/production.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'YOUR_APP.herokuapp.com' }

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"],
    port: 587,
    domain: ENV["EMAIL_DOMAIN"],
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["EMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["EMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }
```

And this to my config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"],
    port: 587,
    domain: ENV["EMAIL_DOMAIN"],
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["EMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["EMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }
```